# Passing Generic Input object to a method C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method ABC() which gets called from two different places in my application. And from both places I have different objects of class which is implemented a common interface "IDestination".

My two classes and Interface are looking like this:

```
public class ClassA: IDestination
{
        public string Var1 { get; set; }    
        public string Var2 { get; set; }    
        public string Var3 { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB: IDestination
{
        public string Var1 { get; set; }
        public string Var2 { get; set; }
        public string Var3 { get; set; }
        public string Var4 { get; set; }
        public string Var5 { get; set; }
}

public interface IDestination
{
        string Var1 { get; set; }
        string Var2 { get; set; }
}
```

As of now Method ABC() accepts the object of classA, I want it can also accept the object of classB. For this I have made my method defination generic like below:

```
public string ABC<T>(T obj)
{

}
```

But, the problem is inside the ABC method I want to access the properties of classes (classA and classB both).

```
public string ABC<T>(T obj)
 {
        //Some code
        obj.var2; //of classA

        obj.var4; //of classB
        //Some code
 }
```

**And I can't allowed to do any changes in the interface.**

How can I achieve this? I do not want to create another method for handling different class objects. Any idea?

Comment: Cast it to the appropriate type? `(ClassB)obj).var4`. For `Var2` you won´t need any cast as it is defined directly on the interface instead within the classes.

Comment: Move those properties to the interface and use `IDestination` as parameter type: `ABC(IDestination obj)`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have tried casting objects also but it is not accepting as method is accepting generics and it doesn't know whether var1 is present in the coming object .

Comment: @DovydasSopa I can't allowed to make any changes in the IDestination object.

Comment: Cast should work if you are not allowed to change the interface.

Comment: You have to add a constraint on `T` to only enable types that implement your interface: `ABC<T>(T obj) where T: IDestination { ... }`

Comment: @DovydasSopa I don´t do this. See my answer, the constraint is defined on the method, not on the interface.

Comment: And can you change any of those classes? Because you just said that you can't modify interface, but what about ClassA and ClassB? Can you change this code?

Comment: @JakubSzumiato I can modify the classes, but problem is these classes is being used at multiple locations in the application (around ~100 places), So I'm avoiding to change it.

Comment: Ok, but adding new interface won't break backward compatibility. The problem is that you're trying to centralize this type-conditional logic whereas it should be distributed/delegated to the objects as those are the ones that know their specifics. I have updated my answer to show you how could you add new interface and implement this method to keep all constraints and not break backward compatibility.

Comment: Or create an abstract class that implements IDestination and specifies virtual methods.  Then ClassA and ClassB could inherit from the abstract class and override any of the methods they  need to.  They would also inherit IDestination from the parent class.  The only question is if you can change method ABC to accept a type of the abstract class instead of IDestination.  See below for my full answer.

Comment: Please also note that as you will get more classes that implement IDestination (ClassC, ClassD, ...ClassABCXYZ, etc.) your ABC method will require more and more modifications. The approach I suggested with interfaces is very similar to the template method design pattern, which initially included abstract classes. You can read about it here: http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern maybe it will put more light on your case.

Comment: @JakubSzumiato I'm trying your approach of creating another interface of common properties and implement it my two classes i.e. classA and classB. Will update you know once it will be done.

Comment: Actually I was more thinking about a method, because if new objects will have more properties, you will need to modify also this new interface, with method you wouldn't need to change it. The question is very tricky because it highly depends on what do you need from those objects.

Comment: @JakubSzumiato Creating new method will not fulfill my need. These classes are sort of entities which rarely changed, so I think creating new interface with required property will works for me.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you have anything I could help you with. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, *interfaces* aren't inherited but *implemented*.

In the other hand, generic parameters can be constrained:

```
public string ABC<T>(T obj) where T : IDestination
```

OP said:

> And I can't allowed to do any changes in the interface.

BTW, with your requirement and just with generic type constraints you won't be able to accept both `classA` and `classB` because C# doesn't support multi-inheritance. If you want to access `classB` members, you'll need to expand your `IDestination` interface to define all properties you want to access in a `classB` typed as `IDestination`:

```
public interface IDestination
{
      string Var1 { get; set; }
      string Var2 { get; set; }
      string Var3 { get; set; }
      string Var4 { get; set; }
      string Var5 { get; set; } 
}
```

Or you can define a second interface with the rest of properties:

```
public interface IDestination2
{
      string Var3 { get; set; }
      string Var4 { get; set; }
      string Var5 { get; set; } 
}
```

...and you'll implement it on `classB`:

```
public class ClassB: IDestination, IDestination2
```

Anyway, the problem here is that you can't constraint a generic parameter to accept two different inheritances of some given classes. That is, for example, if you constraint `T` to be both `IDestination` and `IDestination2`, you won't be able to give `ClassA` as argument, because it doesn't implement `IDestination2`.

OP said:

> I do not want to create another method for handling different class objects.

Actually this could be also solved without generics but with *method overloading* and it's not an evil approach even when you don't want to go this route:

```
public void ABC(IDestination destination) {}
public void ABC(IDestination2 destination) {}

// or directly...

public void ABC(ClassA destination) {}
public void ABC(ClassB destination) {}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to implement this as follows:

```
public string ABC<T>(T obj) where T : IDestination
{
     ClassA a = obj as ClassA;
     ClassB b = obj as ClassB;

     // Now if you want to access Var1, Var2 you can access them
     // using "obj" reference, because T is IDestination
     string var1 = obj.Var1;
     string var2 = obj.Var2;

     if(a != null) 
     {
         // Here access all ClassA members...
     }

     if(b != null)
     {
         // Here access all ClassB members...
     }
}
```

For me, above approach is a design flaw. If I use generic types and interfaces is because I want to work with objects that equal the typing of the generic type parameter.

If I start to perform **downcasts** to particular implementations of the interface, it's like defeating the purpose of using `IDestination` and it seems like your method could be just accepting `object` because your method will access `ClassA` and `ClassB` members instead of `IDestination` ones:

```
public string ABC(object obj)
{
     ClassA a = obj as ClassA;
     ClassB b = obj as ClassB;

     // Now if you want to access Var1, Var2 you can access them
     // using "obj" reference, because T is IDestination
     string var1 = obj.Var1;
     string var2 = obj.Var2;

     if(a != null) 
     {
         // Here access all ClassA members...
     }

     if(b != null)
     {
         // Here access all ClassB members...
     }

     return "";
}
```

### TL;DR

In summary, you should use interfaces to type your objects and generic constraints to guarantee a minimum typing on your references in order to avoid casts. Otherwise, generic typing isn't your solution.

Comment: @DovydasSopa One thing is what OP has said, and another thing is ***if it can be done as the OP has said*** ;P

Answer (score 1):

You should definitly re-think your design. When your method accepts instances of the interface it should work for *all* types, not only a set. Imagine you create a third type that also implements the interface. You would have to re-implement the whole method to support this. Therefor all the properties should be defined on the interface instead of the class-level and then can be accessed within the method.

However if you really have to use your current approach you can simply cast it to the appropriate type:

```
ClassA a = obj as ClassA;
if (a != null) a.Var2 = ...
// this will fail if a user provides an instance of ClassC which also implements the interface
else ((ClassB)obj).Var4 = ...
```

For this to work you will also need a constraint on your gegernic parameter:

```
public string ABC<T>(T obj) where T : IDestination
```

Comment: I would suggest using same cast for `ClassB` as `ClassA`, because user simply might pass anything to this method.

Comment: @DovydasSopa I dropped a comment to show the problem on this approach which I also mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better design is the following:

```
public string ABC<T>(T obj) where T : IDestination
{

}
```

I say so, because since you want a generic method for object that implements the `IDestination` interface, it would be better as a design, If you have declared it as constraint. For this, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Then in order you access the field that you want in the `ABC`, the interface should have all this properties. So If we assume that you want both classes `A`  and `B` have the same three properties `Var1`, `Var2` and `Var3` and you want to access them in the `ABC`, then you have t redecclare your interface as below:

```
public interface IDestination
{
    string Var1 { get; set; }
    string Var2 { get; set; }
    string Var3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But var2 and var3 are not present in the IDestination interface. Can I define like "where T: classA, classB" ??

Comment: I can't allowed to modify the interface as it being used by other places also.

Comment: As I am ware of this cannot be done. A class can inherits only one class. It's not like in C++ where one class can inherit from as many classes you want.

Comment: If you can't, then the only solution I can think is the casting inside `ABC`. Something like this `var a = obj as A;`. Then if `obj` is not null the casting succeeded and you can proceed as you think. Otherwise you declare `var b = obj as B` and make the same check.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be hard to handle type-specific properties in generic method as it doesn't know what is the specifics of such properties. I would recommend delegating this logic to a method, that the classes will implement via interface.

As you mentioned in your comment, you can't change the interface `IDestination` and you don't want to break the compatibility as this solution is already used in many places. So the proposition is not to change `ClassA` and `ClassB` logic that is already working, but add new interface implementation, that will cover this type-conditional logic you wanted to implement in your `ABC` method.

I would add another interface that holds method doing all the type-conditional logic and simply call it in the middle of your ABC class. In order to keep the constraints your generic type would need to implement both IDestination and `IDestinationLogic` interface. Of course the `ABC` method may need slight modifications but it's hard to say how precisely should it look like, given that we totally don't know anything about what it should do.

An example implementation could look like that:

```
public class GenericMethodClass
{

    public string ABC<T>(T obj) where T : IDestination, IDestinationLogic
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        //some code happens here

        var typeConditionalLogicResult = obj.DoSomething(); 

        // do more stuff with according to the result of type-specific calculations

        return result;
    }
}


public class ClassA: IDestination, IDestinationLogic
{
    public string Var1 { get; set; }    
    public string Var2 { get; set; }    
    public string Var3 { get; set; }

    public string DoSomething()
    {
        return Var2;        
    }
}

public class ClassB: IDestination, IDestinationLogic
{
    public string Var1 { get; set; }
    public string Var2 { get; set; }
    public string Var3 { get; set; }
    public string Var4 { get; set; }
    public string Var5 { get; set; }

    public string DoSomething()
    {
        return Var4;        
    }
}

public interface IDestination
{
    string Var1 { get; set; }
    string Var2 { get; set; }   
}

public interface IDestinationLogic
{
    string DoSomething();   
}
```

The approach I suggested with interfaces is very similar to the template method design pattern, which initially included abstract classes. You can read about it here: http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern maybe it will put more light on your case

Answer (score 0):

Well, to achieve what you want you need to implement the ABC method to accept a type of IDestination:

```
public string ABC<T>(T obj) where T : IDestination
```

But for that to work, you then have to change your interface to have all the methods you want to access:

```
    public interface IDestination
    {
        string Var1 { get; set; }
        string Var2 { get; set; }
        string Var3 { get; set; }
        string Var4 { get; set; }
        string Var5 { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you have to change your classes to implement all the members of the interface which means you might end up with something like this:

```
    public class ClassA : IDestination
    {
        public string Var1 { get; set; }
        public string Var2 { get; set; }
        public string Var3 { get; set; }

        public string Var4
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public string Var5
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ClassB : IDestination
    {
        public string Var1 { get; set; }
        public string Var2 { get; set; }
        public string Var3 { get; set; }
        public string Var4 { get; set; }
        public string Var5 { get; set; }
    }
```

But it doesn't make a lot of sense to have the extra methods implemented in ClassA if they just throw an exception.  So you might as well just fully implement them.  But then ClassA and ClassB are identical.  So you have to ask yourself what is unique enough about each class to justify a separate concrete implementation of IDestination?  Answering that question will guide you on what to do.

**EDIT:** 
Since you can't change the interface, are you forced to use the interface in method ABC?  Can you create an abstract class that both ClassA and ClassB inherit from?

```
public abstract class ClassAB : IDestination //might not need the interface
{
  public virtual string Var1 { get; set; }
  public virtual string Var2 { get; set; }
  public virtual string Var3 { get; set; }
  public virtual string Var4 { get; set; }
  public virtual string Var5 { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : ClassAB
{
   //override any of the virtual methods needed
}

public class ClassB : ClassAB
{
   //override any of the virtual methods needed
}
```

Then change ABC method:

```
public string ABC(ClassAB classAB)
{
  //all the methods are available on classAB
}
```

Both ClassA and ClassB would still be of type IDestination because the abstract parent class implements it.  The only question is if you can change method ABC to expect a type of ClassAB instead of IDestination?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reflection class to handle that problem, you can get the properties of parameter in the runtime and you can use also.

```
Type type = typeof(obj);
PropertyInfo[] propertyList = type.GetProperties();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Reflection for getting these value like this:

```
public static string ABC<T>(T obj) 
    {
        string s=string.Empty;
        //Some code
        if(obj is ClassA)
            s = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Var2").GetValue(obj, null).ToString(); //of classA

        if (obj is ClassB)
        s = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Var4").GetValue(obj,null).ToString(); //of classB
        //Some code
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: If you already know if it's `ClassA` or `ClassB`, why you need reflection after all?